# Reduce a list of data.frames to a non-redundant data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reduce

I have a `list` of `data.frame`s where certain `data.frame` elements may have all their columns and their values contained within another `data.frame` element.

Here's an example `list`:

```
df.list <- list(df1 = data.frame(id = rep("i1",6), name = c("t1_1","t1_2","t1_3","b_1","b_2","b_3"), replicate = rep(1:3,2), condition = c(rep("t1",3),rep("b",3)), y = c(0.5,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.05)),
                df2 = data.frame(id = rep("i1",6), name = c("t2_1","t2_2","t2_3","b_1","b_2","b_3"), replicate = rep(1:3,2), condition = c(rep("t2",3),rep("b",3)), y = c(0.8,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.1,0.05)),
                df3 = data.frame(id = rep("i1",6), name = c("t1_1","t1_2","t1_3","b_1","b_2","b_3"), replicate = rep(1:3,2), age = rep(c(10,20,30),2), condition = c(rep("t1",3),rep("b",3)), y = c(0.5,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.05)),
                df4 = data.frame(id = rep("i1",6), name = c("t2_1","t2_2","t2_3","b_1","b_2","b_3"), replicate = rep(1:3,2), age = rep(c(10,20,30),2), condition = c(rep("t2",3),rep("b",3)), y = c(0.8,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.1,0.05)))
```

So `df.list$df1` is contained within `df.list$df3` and `df.list$df2` is contained within `df.list$df4`, because `df.list$df3` and `df.list$df4` have the `age` column which `df.list$df1` and `df.list$df2` do not have.

I would like to `Reduce` this `list` into a non-redundant `data.frame`.

```
list(unique(Reduce(rbind,df.list)))
```

wouldn't work because the `data.frame` elements have different columns (the `age` column in `df.list$df3` and `df.list$df4`), so I'm looking for something equivalent that will detect that `df.list$df1` and `df.list$df2` are contained (and therefore redundant) within `df.list$df3` and `df.list$df4`, respectively.

In the case of the example above the resulting data.frame will be:

```
unique(rbind(df.list$df3, df.list$df4))
```

Comment: BTW (not your ultimate question): don't rbind on each iteration, it scales horribly (read [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), chapter 2 *Growing Objects*); this is the same as using `Reduce`. Instead, `alldat <- do.call(rbind, df.list)`.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a reductive `merge`, but you'd need to determine what you want to do if/when `y` is different (b/w `df1` and `df3`). While not true, a `coalesce` method for joining and bringing in missing fields would necessarily "lose" new non-`NA` values.

Comment: `library(dplyr); do.call(bind_rows, df.list) %>% distinct_all()`

Comment: Your title says "non-redundant", but the last three rows of `rbind(df.list$df3, df.list$df4)` are duplicates. Can you clarify?

Comment: Just clarified my post

Answer (score 2):

If you are intending to reduce out the `NA` values in `age`, thinking that they will auto-update, then try this:

```r
Reduce(function(a, b) {
  out <- merge(a, b,
    by = setdiff(intersect(names(a), names(b)), c("age","y")), suffixes = c("", ".z"),
    all = TRUE)
  dotz <- grep("\\.z$", names(out), value = TRUE)
  noz <- gsub("\\.z$", "", dotz)
  dotz <- dotz[noz %in% names(out)]
  noz <- noz[noz %in% names(out)]
  out[noz] <- Map(function(a, b) ifelse(is.na(a), b, a), out[noz], out[dotz])
  out[setdiff(names(out), dotz)]
}, df.list)
#   id name replicate condition    y age
# 1 i1  b_1         1         b 0.20  10
# 2 i1  b_2         2         b 0.10  20
# 3 i1  b_3         3         b 0.05  30
# 4 i1 t1_1         1        t1 0.50  10
# 5 i1 t1_2         2        t1 0.60  20
# 6 i1 t1_3         3        t1 0.20  30
# 7 i1 t2_1         1        t2 0.80  10
# 8 i1 t2_2         2        t2 0.90  20
# 9 i1 t2_3         3        t2 0.70  30
```

Note that when both values of `y` (for example) are non-`NA`, this process will silently drop the second (and subsequent) non-`NA` values.

Answer (score 1):

As r2evans mentioned in the coments, `Reduce()` is actually not the best way to go here.

```r
df.list |> 
  seq_along() |>
  # for each data frame, check if every element is also element in one of the others
  lapply(\(x) lapply(df.list[-x], \(y) all(df.list[[x]] %in% y))) |> 
  sapply(\(x) unlist(x) |> Negate(any)()) |> 
  {\(.) df.list[.]}() |> 
  do.call(what = rbind)
#>       id name replicate age condition    y
#> df3.1 i1 t1_1         1  10        t1 0.50
#> df3.2 i1 t1_2         2  20        t1 0.60
#> df3.3 i1 t1_3         3  30        t1 0.20
#> df3.4 i1  b_1         1  10         b 0.20
#> df3.5 i1  b_2         2  20         b 0.10
#> df3.6 i1  b_3         3  30         b 0.05
#> df4.1 i1 t2_1         1  10        t2 0.80
#> df4.2 i1 t2_2         2  20        t2 0.90
#> df4.3 i1 t2_3         3  30        t2 0.70
#> df4.4 i1  b_1         1  10         b 0.20
#> df4.5 i1  b_2         2  20         b 0.10
#> df4.6 i1  b_3         3  30         b 0.05
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>